# Sanitizing post content for use in an email

Tags: custom-post-types, email, the-content, sanitization

I'm sending the content of a custom post type in a plain text email (it's to send competition entries to a panel of judges), so I need to make sure that `$post->post_content` is correctly sanitized first.

Is there a filter I can use for this, or if not, what sanitization do I need to do?

Update: I've just found `wp_strip_all_tags` in `wp-includes/formatting.php`, is this what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use `sanitize_email();` as follows:

```
return( sanitize_email( $email ) );
```

Here is the Codex link so you have it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_email

Cheers!

Comment: that's great thanks, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Yeah, in the [Professional WordPress Plugin Development by Wrox](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development.productCd-1118075307.html) it explains in detail why it's best to use the `sanitize_email` function. There's also a validation function `is_email` which is really cool too. Cheers!

Comment: But the questioner wants to sanitize the message body and this function is for sanitising an email address.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the accepted answer here was accepted since it is not actually going to work.

The OP was how to sanitize the *email **content***. `sanitize_email()` sanitizes an *email **address***.  Sure, it won't throw an error, but it doesn't actually ***do*** anything.

To sanitize the content, it depends on what is actually intended to be in the content to determine what would be appropriate.

One generic possibility would be [`sanitize_textarea_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data).  This is for the HTML text area field, but it will maintain line breaks.  It will strip out all tags.

However, if the email is intended to be HTML formatted, then you don't want to strip all tags.  In that case, you'd want to use something that allows the tags you want, but strips out the tags you don't.  For that, use [`wp_kses()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses).

To use `wp_kses()` to sanitize your HTML email content, pass the content and an array including allowed tags to the function:

```
$allowed_tags = array(
  'p' => array(
    'id' => array(),
    'class' => array(),
  ),
  'a' => array(
    'href' => array(),
    'title' => array()
  ),
  'br' => array(),
  'em' => array(),
  'strong' => array(),
);

$sanitized_content = wp_kses( $post->post_content, $allowed_tags );
```

A simplified variation on that above method would be to use `wp_kses_post()`. This function has preset the allowed tags, which makes it easier since you don't have to define what tags and attributes are allowed.  It's primarily whatever is allowed for post content.

```
$sanitized_content = wp_kses_post( $post->post_content );
```

If it's regular post content, then it probably already went through this.  If it's a custom post type, then it depends.

So which should you use? As I mentioned in the beginning, it depends on the content and how it will be used.  If it's plain text, use something that strips all tags. If it's HTML, use `wp_kses()` or a variant.

See related information on sanitizing in [the WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data).